# Global socially acceptable way of acknowledging that I'm being a "pedantic w****r"?

Tags: phrase-requests, politeness, australian-english

I'm Australian and would not hesitate to call myself a "pedantic wanker" in public (because, well... I often am!).

There is a very small chance that someone (most likely elderly or particularly conservative) may be offended. IMO though, it's quite socially acceptable, and unless you are in a particularly formal setting, the risk of it being considered offensive is extremely low.

However, I work with a lot of people, from all over the world. Whilst my colleagues know me and have learned the context of my speech patterns, I also realise that the casual Australian vernacular can be a little harsh for those that are unaccustomed.

I'm pretty casual by nature and wish to be authentic. So I am looking for something that is not too formal or contrite and maintains a sense of playfulness. I.e. I'm denigrating myself, but mainly as a tool to soften the impact of my critique of someone else, rather than seriously putting myself down. So I'm looking for something that I could say in a similar tongue in cheek way.

Explicitly, I'm wondering how I would best rephrase a sentence such as "I just wanted to be the pedantic wanker and point that out!" [that = a mistake you made that doesn't really matter].

Comment: Many folks are only familiar with "wank" as meaning "masturbate", and would not consider it polite speech, even in a jocular sense.

Comment: @HotLicks The Australian vernacular takes some getting used to.

Comment: @HotLicks - yes, same meaning here too. But so long as the context is jocular and/or aimed at a one's self, a friend, or a public figure it's unlikely to even raise an eyebrow. Having said that, I suspect that even in Australia, there are social strata where it's not considered polite and/or acceptable.

Comment: "Just being a smart ass," or "Not to be a smart ass," seems to work fine as an indicator for me. Not sure how it fares internationally. TBH, if you just said "...being a wanker" to me, I'd get it from what little British or Australian TV I've watched, so seems fairly well known--though my TV viewing may not be inline with the majority, so take my opinion with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might say that you just wanted to be "that guy" and point out the mistake.

The usage of the term is extremely broad, but it's within coo-ee of your original expression, is widely understood, and is socially acceptable when used in a self-deprecating manner.

> **"That guy"**
>   (T)he basic definition for being "that guy" is to just be as annoying as humanly possible at any and all types of social functions, and annoying in many different ways(.)
>   [- Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%22That%20guy%22)